# How to create an app that is always listening for voice commands and can exececute a "tap" in another app?

Tags: android, automation, voice-recognition

I am creating an Android app for a friend who is trying to help paraplegics with home automation. I need my app to do three things and just need to get pointed in the right direction for each, because I'm fairly new to Android and am a bit lost. Also note that the device can be rooted.

1: The app needs to be always listening to a particular command, such as "Home Control System".

2: Once the command is said it needs to launch a third-party app that controls home automation.

3: Once that app is open, my app needs to be able to tap a "voice recognition" button in the third-party app so that the paraplegic can control the home automation. (I've read that I may be able to use the INJECT_EVENTS permission here, but unsure how to actually create the touch event).

Comment: Whats the device? and Android version?

Comment: Can be any device and any android version.